# Counting number of occurrences of a char in a string in C

Tags: c, string, char

I have the string `str`

```
char *str = "100.10b.100.100";
```

I want to count the occurrences of `'.'` in `str`, preferably a one-liner. (If possible no loops)

My approach would be the standard `strchr`:

```
  int i = 0;
  char *pch=strchr(str,'.');
  while (pch!=NULL) {
    i++;
    pch=strchr(pch+1,'.');
  }
```

Comment: To the mantra bag - what have you tried?  what about it doesn't work? .......

Comment: @KevinDTimm: I posted my approach.

Comment: As tvanfosson pointed out, you can do it with recursion, and perhaps that's what your teacher wanted to see you do, but it's an utterly idiotic way to do it. It will result in *stack overflow* for large enough strings... and not the good kind of SO that does your homework for you, the bad kind! ;-)

Answer (score 92):

Here's the way I'd do it (minimal number of variables needed):

```
for (i=0; s[i]; s[i]=='.' ? i++ : *s++);
```

Comment: No, I'm incrementing either `s` or `i` depending on whether `s[i]` is a `'.'` or not. The expression `s+i` always increases by exactly 1 at each iteration, but it could be the counter (`i`) or the base pointer (`s`) that causes `s+i` to increase.

Comment: I would call that *clever*.  In code, *clever* is not always a good thing.  I usually prefer *obvious*.

Comment: @R -- that's because it was too *clever* for me to catch upon first waking.

Comment: Will this algorithm ever stop? It does not handle \0.

Comment: If you're already incrementing s, why not use i entirely for counting occurences of '.'? for (; *s; i += *s == '.', s++)

Comment: +1 this is really really neat. As a point of interest: at -O3 level (Apple clang-503.0.38, LLVM version 5.1), this is slightly less efficient - 2 instructions, 14 vs 16 ;) - than the more verbose for(string) if(char) { incrementCounter }. Lower memory footprint though (one less variable needed obviously).

Comment: seems not to work today, with `int i; char *s` : `pointer/integer type mismatch in conditional expression`

Comment: I had to think for a minute on how that would work. I'd recommend changing the loop condition from `s[i]` to `s[i] != '\0'` for clarity.

Comment: @cp.engr: In that case maybe we should make it `(s[i] != '\0') != 0` for added clarity? ;-)

Comment: The dereferencing is cryptic - took me a bit to realize that the increment still affects the pointer, not the character to which it points. (i.e. It's `*s++` == `*(s++)`, not `(*s)++`.) But if you're committed to a single line, it's necessary to satisfy the compiler.

Comment: I wonder how many people like me spent all day trying to figure this out.

Comment: a clever solution, but this will move the pointer to another location so you won't be able to use the string s again

Comment: This answer would be more helpful if it included the instantiation of `i` and `s`.

Comment: This doesn't look clever to me, it looks confused. For example, I'm pretty sure dereferencing `s` at the end there is a no-op: `*s++` increments the pointer `s`, then dereferences its value, but... doesn't do anything with the value. Incrementing the `s` pointer, or the `i` pointer, then using the combined result... is extremely confusing, and I doubt it costs less than unconditionally incrementing `s`.

Comment: In other words, the loop with `*s++` is identical to the loop with `s++`. If I wanted to put all my logic in the loop itself (which is a bad idea to begin with), I'd settle on `for (const char *c = my_string; *c; (i += *c == '.'), c++);`. K&R stated in The C Programming Language Vol. 2 that putting the semicolon on a newline, indented, is a better idea to make clear this is the intended behaviour. Finally, this code is still confusing, relying on the boolean operator returning `i += 0` for false, and `i += 1` for true, so that's the bit that I'd move to the body of the loop.

Answer (score 37):

OK, a non-loop implementation (and yes, it is meant as a joke).

```
size_t CountChars(const char *s, char c)
{
  size_t nCount=0;
  if (s[0])
  {
    nCount += ( s[0]==c);
    if (s[1])
    {
      nCount += ( s[1]==c);
      if (s[2])
      {
        nCount += ( s[2]==c);
        if (s[3])
        {
          nCount += ( s[3]==c);
          if (s[4])
          {
            nCount += ( s[4]==c);
            if (s[5])
            {
              nCount += ( s[5]==c);
              if (s[6])
              {
                nCount += ( s[6]==c);
                if (s[7])
                {
                  nCount += ( s[7]==c);
                  if (s[8])
                  {
                    nCount += ( s[8]==c);
                    if (s[9])
                    {
                      nCount += ( s[9]==c);
                      if (s[10])
                      {
                        /* too long */
                        assert(0);
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return nCount;
}
```

Comment: I think you've doubled your 8 here: `nCount += ( s[88]==c);`. You should have written a C code generator that called `cc` via `system` to produce the final result. Or even better, a recursive code generator to avoid loops in the code generator.

Comment: Seven years later somebody has down-voted this without even a comment as to why.  This was a comical piece of code and says so at the top.  It illustrates the impracticality of the question.

Is somebody worried that it is bad style???

Comment: i found this ancient joke, but now i'm curious: will the compiler press this down to a single count loop using the ecx register, or is this madness really going to compile into a full jump table?

Answer (score 32):

Look, ma, no loops.

```
int c = countChars( s, '.' );

int countChars( char* s, char c )
{
    return *s == '\0'
              ? 0
              : countChars( s + 1, c ) + (*s == c);
}
```

But, I'd actually use a loop, since that's the correct control structure to use.

Comment: ah, sweetness and light :) - but can't you do a ternary so there's only one return (and no if)?

Comment: I think the `|` is supposed to be a `:`.  Also, "no loops" is nice, but it's not exactly as readable nor maintainable as a loop, and it's not going to be faster either.  (Though it may not be slower, thanks to tail recursion.)  Clever code is not always good code, especially when it obfuscates meaning.

Comment: But you *are* using a loop! (You are just not using the for/while keywords).

Comment: @cdhowie - you do realize that this homework and that's why the problem was stated this way, right?

Comment: @pst -- not a loop, it uses recursion, which in this case is arguably worse.

Comment: @tvanfosson How is recursion not used as a/an (implicit) loop here? ;-) One could argue the same for my "GOTO" answer.

Comment: @pst one would be wrong. Using a goto the way you did *is* a loop. Recursion is not a loop, though yes, you can accomplish the same things with recursion as you can with looping (and some compilers in some languages will even turn tail-calls into gotos, hence getting a loop in the compiled code when there was none in the source).

Comment: @KevinDTimm: why would homework assignments say, "if possible no loops"? It's always possible to express loops as recursion.

Comment: @Steve - whenever I see 'count' and 'no loops' in the same sentence - I smell homework.  It's one of the easiest ways to ease someone into recursion - and as tvanfosson has stated - not the best way to actually do it.

Comment: @pst -- if we were talking about a functional language, then I could see your point about interpreting it as a loop: "a sequence of statements iterated successively", but in C there's typically a distinction between an iterative loop and recursion.

Comment: @KevinDTimm: I'm not saying it's not homework, just that I don't think that homework would state the problem in this way. I suppose it could be stated, A: implement the function, B (optional): implement it without a loop. If the assignment is to implement it recursively then it's not "no loops, if possible". It's "no loops".

Comment: @KevinDTimm: wish homework was like this back then! JFTR, it is not homework.

Comment: If you pass the current count as a parameter too, instead of accumulating it by adding 1, you could make use of tail-call optimization.

Comment: Change your tail call to `return countChars(s + 1, c) + *s == c;`.

Comment: @Chris Lutz - I actually dislike the dependence on weak-typing, but the standard does say that equality tests should return 1 when equal so I suppose it's ok.  Because it allows me to shorten the expression and convert the outer if/then to a ternary operation without losing readability, I'll go ahead and do it.

Comment: You need `*s==c` in parentheses. `+` has higher precedence than `==`, obviously.

Comment: @tvanfosson - Is it a weak-typing issue if it's defined to return an `int` by the standard? (That's how it's defined, right? It's not defined to return any `bool` type that C89 doesn't have I hope.) Also, the conditional in your shortened version is wrong! It should be `*s == '\0'`, not `s == '\0'`. @R.. - D'oh!

Comment: @Chris -- fixed.  I would call it a weak typing issue.  In a strongly typed language comparison operators would return a boolean type, not an integer type.  It wouldn't even compile since it wouldn't be a valid expression.

Comment: @tvanfosson - That makes sense. BTW, here's a version that might be faster, since it abstracts the character searching into the standard library: `int countChars(char *s, char c) { return (s = strchr(s, c)) ? countChars(s + 1, c) + 1 : 0 }`

Comment: @Chris - strchr undoubtedly uses a loop internally.  my goal was pure recursion.

Comment: I can smell a stack overflow ... Oh, wait, that's the name of this forum!

Answer (score 18):

Without loops is going to be hard since there's no standard C library function that does this and you need to look at all chars :)

I'll take the obvious solution:

```
int i, count;
for (i=0, count=0; str[i]; i++)
  count += (str[i] == '.');
```

Feel free to squeeze the two lines of actual code into one if you have to :)

Comment: `for (i=0; s[i]; s[i]=='.' ? i++ : s++);`

Comment: That modifies s, though. I've tried to leave the original values alone :) Other than that, nice!

Answer (score 6):

If you're keen on a one-liner (well, two-):

```
size_t count = 0;
while(*str) if (*str++ == '.') ++count;
```

Comment: Here's it reduced to a single for statement including the loop variable and output: `for (size_t i=0; s[i] || printf("%d\n", i)>INT_MAX; s[i]=='.'?i++:s++);` ;-)

Answer (score 5):

I'd still throw this in a function, parametrizing the source string and the character to search for.

```
int count_characters(const char *str, char character)
{
    const char *p = str;
    int count = 0;

    do {
        if (*p == character)
            count++;
    } while (*(p++));

    return count;
}
```

Comment: Only actual practical answer... especially if you prefer readable code. However I had to replace if (*p == character) with if(strcmp(p, character)) otherwise it wouldn't work.

Comment: Yeah probably something I changed, didn't make an exact copy. Still I have some actual use for it so thanks. :-)

Answer (score 2):

//I guess it should work. One line and no loop.

```
int countChar(char *s, char letter) {
    return ((*s) ? (((*s++ == letter)? 1:0)) + countChar (s, letter)): 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do it without a loop is recursion.  The following is included for fun, but is ***NOT*** recommended as a solution:

```
size_t CountChars(char* s, char c)
{
    return *s ? ((c==*s) + CountChars(s+1)) : 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont like goto,still,

```
    int i=0,count=0;
    char *str = "100.10b.100.100";
    a:
    if(str[i]=='.')
        count++;
    i++;
    if(str[i])
    goto a;
```

Answer (score 1):

everytime you run this code baby dijkstra cries :)

```
  1
  2
  3
  4 #include <ctype.h>
  5 #include <stdio.h>
  6 #include <stdlib.h>
  7 #include <string.h>
  8
  9
 10 size_t bytewise_pop_count(
 11     unsigned char * bp, size_t l
 12 ) {
 13     if ( (bp) && (l) ) {
 14         return bytewise_pop_count(bp+1, l-1) + (bp[0] ? 1 : 0);
 15     }
 16     return 0;
 17 }
 18
 19 void mercilessly_complement_bytes(
 20     unsigned char * bp, size_t l
 21 ) {
 22 /*
 23     transform
 24         0 -> 1
 25         !0 -> 0
 26 */
 27     if ( (bp) && (l) ) {
 28         bp[0] = bp[0] ? 0 : 1;
 29         mercilessly_complement_bytes(bp+1, l-1);
 30     }
 31 }
 32
 33 void xor_bytes(
 34     unsigned char * bp1, unsigned char * bp2, size_t l
 35 ) {
 36     /* stores result in bp2 */
 37     if ( (bp1) && (bp2) && (l) ) {
 38         bp2[0] ^= bp1[0];
 39         xor_bytes(bp1+1, bp2+1, l-1);
 40     }
 41 }
 42
 43
 44 int main(int argc, char * * argv) {
 45     char c;
 46     size_t count;
 47     size_t l;
 48     char * string;
 49     char * t;
 50
 51     if (argc < 3) {
 52         fprintf(stderr,
 53             "\n"
 54             "==> not enough arguments -- need char and string\n"
 55             "\n"
 56         );
 57         return EXIT_FAILURE;
 58     }
 59
 60     c = argv[1][0];
 61     string = argv[2];
 62
 63     if ( l = strlen(string) ) {
 64         t = malloc(l);
 65         memset(t, c, l);
 66         xor_bytes(string, t, l);
 67         mercilessly_complement_bytes(t, l);
 68         count = bytewise_pop_count(t, l);
 69         free(t);
 70     } else {
 71         count = 0;
 72     }
 73
 74     if ( isprint(c) ) {
 75         printf(
 76             "\n"
 77             "==> occurences of char ``%c'' in string ``%s'': %zu\n"
 78             "\n"
 79             , c, string ? string : "<NULL>", count
 80         );
 81     } else {
 82         printf(
 83             "\n"
 84             "==> occurences of char ``%hhu'' in string ``%s'': %zu\n"
 85             "\n"
 86             , c, string ? string : "<NULL>", count
 87         );
 88     }
 89     return EXIT_SUCCESS;
 90 }
```

Comment: Not quite the `one line (if possible no loops)` asked for!

Comment: AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAHHH

Answer (score 1):

## If you really want a one-liner:

- keeping **str** intact *(in case you want to use it later)*

  `for(i = 0, c = 0; str[i] != '\0'; (str[i] == '.')? c++: 0, i++);`
- if you don't care about **str** variable

  `for(c = 0; *str != '\0'; (*str == '.')? c++: 0, str++);`

  - *additionally you can subtract previous strlen to make it usable again*

but as you can see, it's pretty ugly so I would advise doing something like this:

```
for(i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
{
    if(str[i] == '.')
        ++c;
}
```

or

```
for(c = 0; *str != '\0'; str++)
{
    if(*str == '.')
        ++c;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using memchr:

```
size_t nOccurrences(const char* buffer, const char character, size_t bufferLength) {
    size_t result = 0;
    size_t residualLength = bufferLength;
    
    do {
        void* start = (void*)(buffer + bufferLength - residualLength);
        void* occurrence = memchr(start, character, residualLength);
        if(NULL == occurrence) {
            break;
        }
        ++result;
        residualLength = bufferLength - ((char*)occurrence - buffer) - 1;
    } while(1);
    
    return result;
}
```