# Generating directory structure from string

Tags: c, tree, directory, structure

I'm trying to generate a directory tree structure from a string that I enter into my program. Example of string:

```
/users/username/documents/folder/file.txt
```

I want to create the above directory structure inside a predetermined folder e.g. "backup". When done right, the resulting directory tree would be:

```
/backup/users/username/documents/folder/file.txt
```

But I don't want to copy all the files inside the "documents" folder or "folder" folder etc. The only file I want to be copied over is the single text file at the end of the path.

Would I have to loop through the indexes of the string and separate it using the "/" ? It seems a bit tedious and I was wondering if there was a quicker more efficient way to code it?

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: It depends on what system call you have to use to create a directory. If this is UNIX or Linux you would call mkdir() for each directory in the tree.  Starting with whatever directory in your example string does not already exist.  If /backup exists already, start with /backup/users.

Comment: Under Windows, use the SHCreateDirectoryEx windows function. It creates all missing parts of the path in one go.

Comment: I am using gcc compiler on MAC OS X

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the POSIX function `mkdir(2)` you need to create missing directories one by one.

If you are prepared to be a bit less portable
it can be done with a single `system` call. How you do it depends on your OS.

In Linux/UNIX you can create all missing directories in one call with `mkdir -p`.

In windows you can use SHCreateDirectoryEx (according to the comment by Baldrick).

Answer (score 0):

I tried to write a program that does the above mentioned job and found the following one to work.

You can use `strtok()` to extract all individual directories from the input and apply 
`mkdir()` for each subdirectory. The string after the last `/` is the file name and *I don't know if there is a better way to parse the string using strtok() the way I do*: I call a function countChars() (borrowed from https://stackoverflow.com/a/4235545/1024474) to determine the number of `/` in the path to get the number of folders to be created and use a `while` loop accordingly to create the dirs.

Finally, I use creat() to create a file with the file name of the specified path. In your code you would copy the content of the original file to the new file.

The following code assumes that your are already in the predetermined `backup/` folder and the path is something like `users/username/documents/folder/file.txt`

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

int countChars( char* s, char c )
{
    return *s == '\0'
              ? 0
              : countChars( s + 1, c ) + (*s == c);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

   mode_t mode = S_IRWXU;

   umask(0);

   char buffer[512];
   char *b;
   char c[512];
   int n, i=0;

   strcpy(buffer, argv[1]);

   n = countChars(buffer, '/');

   printf("%d\n", n);

   b = strtok(buffer, "/");

   while (i<n)
   {
    i++;
    printf("%s\n", b);
    if (mkdir(b, mode) == -1) {
        printf("error when creating dir\n");
    }
    chdir(b);
    b = strtok(NULL, "/");
   }

   if (creat(b, mode) == -1) {
       printf("error when creating file\n");
   }

   return 0;

}
```

If a folder already exists, the programs prints an error (i.e. a notification), but proceeds.