# How to make cipher more efficient

Tags: c, algorithm, encryption, big-o

I have written the code for a rail fence cipher decoder, the input provided is the number of rails and the already encoded text. The decoder works, however, it only works for small inputs or short words. If i try entering a paragraph with a rails of 10 no output shows up.

I am still trying to grasp the concept of Order of a function, so I'm unsure of the order of my program. How do I make it more efficient or improve its efficiency?

Decrypt Function:

```
void decrypt(int rail,char *cipher) {
 int length = strlen(cipher);
 int i, j;
 int counter=0,num=0,in=1;

 int railfence[rail][100],count[100];

for(i=0;i < length;i++) 
          count[i]=0;

    for(i=0;i < length;i++){

        if(num + in == rail) in =- 1;

        else if(num + in == -1)in = 1;

        railfence[num][count[num]] = i;
        ++count[num];
        num += in;
    }
char buffer[1000];

for(i=0;i < rail;i++)
    for(j=0;j < count[i];j++){
        buffer[railfence[i][j]] = cipher[counter];
        ++counter;
    }

  buffer[length]='\0';
  printf("%s\n",buffer);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does the program finish running, but not display output when you enter a larger input? Or does it just never finish?

Comment: Seems to me the rail cipher has order 1. In other words, it should finish as good as immediately, one operation per character (put character on rails, using simple calculations).

Comment: I've got a very efficient implementation that simply places the characters right in place, if you're interested. Beware that you should learn how to puzzle instead of copying code, so this may not help you.

Answer (score 2):

When your `rail` is larger than the message length, your have uninitialised string lengths for each rail. You initialise `count` in a loop from 0 to the message length, but you should initalise a length for each rail:

```
for (i = 0; i < rail; i++)
    count[i] = 0;
```

That change should fix your error.

You are using variable-length arrays, and you know the size of these arrays. So there's no need to guess the dimensions (and make them large enough just in case). You can determine the lengths:

```
int zigzag[rail][length / (rail - 1) + 1];
int count[rail];

char buffer[length + 1];
```

(The `zigzag` array's inner rails have twice the number of letters in the two outer rails. Considering top and bottom rail as one, each rail must cater for at most `length / (rail - 1) + 1`. The `+ 1` at the end catches division cutoffs.)

The algorithm can probably be made more efficient by walking the message without an additional two-dimensional array. Traverse rail `i` with an alternating stride of `2 * (rail - 1 - i)` and `2 * i`. You must take care not to treat the letters of the top and bottom rails twice (when the stride is zero).

Answer (score 1):

This should be considered a teaser for an optimal implementation:

```
if (rail == 0 || rail == railCount - 1) {
    plaintextOffset = rail + offInRail * (iterfreq * 2);
} else {
    if (offInRail % 2 == 0) {
        plaintextOffset = rail + offInRail * iterfreq;
    } else {
        plaintextOffset = railCount - rail - 1 + offInRail * iterfreq;
    }
}
```

You'll need to iterate over the rails, keeping the starting offset of the rail in the ciphertext in mind. Then you can iterate over the possible characters in the rail, while testing if plaintextOffset is not too high.

Example output using the Wikipedia plaintext as test vector:

```
Rails: 3, size 25
CT rail 0 : 0 + 0 = 0 <-> 0 PT
CT rail 0 : 0 + 1 = 1 <-> 4 PT
CT rail 0 : 0 + 2 = 2 <-> 8 PT
CT rail 0 : 0 + 3 = 3 <-> 12 PT
CT rail 0 : 0 + 4 = 4 <-> 16 PT
CT rail 0 : 0 + 5 = 5 <-> 20 PT
CT rail 0 : 0 + 6 = 6 <-> 24 PT
CT rail 0 : 7 + 7 = 14 <-> 28 PT (too high)
CT rail 1 : 7 + 0 = 7 <-> 1 PT
CT rail 1 : 7 + 1 = 8 <-> 3 PT
CT rail 1 : 7 + 2 = 9 <-> 5 PT
CT rail 1 : 7 + 3 = 10 <-> 7 PT
CT rail 1 : 7 + 4 = 11 <-> 9 PT
CT rail 1 : 7 + 5 = 12 <-> 11 PT
CT rail 1 : 7 + 6 = 13 <-> 13 PT
CT rail 1 : 7 + 7 = 14 <-> 15 PT
CT rail 1 : 7 + 8 = 15 <-> 17 PT
CT rail 1 : 7 + 9 = 16 <-> 19 PT
CT rail 1 : 7 + 10 = 17 <-> 21 PT
CT rail 1 : 7 + 11 = 18 <-> 23 PT
CT rail 1 : 19 + 12 = 31 <-> 25 PT (too high)
CT rail 2 : 19 + 0 = 19 <-> 2 PT
CT rail 2 : 19 + 1 = 20 <-> 6 PT
CT rail 2 : 19 + 2 = 21 <-> 10 PT
CT rail 2 : 19 + 3 = 22 <-> 14 PT
CT rail 2 : 19 + 4 = 23 <-> 18 PT
CT rail 2 : 19 + 5 = 24 <-> 22 PT
CT rail 2 : 25 + 6 = 31 <-> 26 PT (too high)
WECRLTEERDSOEEFEAOCAIVDEN
Rails: 3, size 25
CT rail 0 : 0 + 0 = 0 <-> 0 PT
CT rail 0 : 0 + 1 = 1 <-> 4 PT
CT rail 0 : 0 + 2 = 2 <-> 8 PT
CT rail 0 : 0 + 3 = 3 <-> 12 PT
CT rail 0 : 0 + 4 = 4 <-> 16 PT
CT rail 0 : 0 + 5 = 5 <-> 20 PT
CT rail 0 : 0 + 6 = 6 <-> 24 PT
CT rail 0 : 7 + 7 = 14 <-> 28 PT (too high)
CT rail 1 : 7 + 0 = 7 <-> 1 PT
CT rail 1 : 7 + 1 = 8 <-> 3 PT
CT rail 1 : 7 + 2 = 9 <-> 5 PT
CT rail 1 : 7 + 3 = 10 <-> 7 PT
CT rail 1 : 7 + 4 = 11 <-> 9 PT
CT rail 1 : 7 + 5 = 12 <-> 11 PT
CT rail 1 : 7 + 6 = 13 <-> 13 PT
CT rail 1 : 7 + 7 = 14 <-> 15 PT
CT rail 1 : 7 + 8 = 15 <-> 17 PT
CT rail 1 : 7 + 9 = 16 <-> 19 PT
CT rail 1 : 7 + 10 = 17 <-> 21 PT
CT rail 1 : 7 + 11 = 18 <-> 23 PT
CT rail 1 : 19 + 12 = 31 <-> 25 PT (too high)
CT rail 2 : 19 + 0 = 19 <-> 2 PT
CT rail 2 : 19 + 1 = 20 <-> 6 PT
CT rail 2 : 19 + 2 = 21 <-> 10 PT
CT rail 2 : 19 + 3 = 22 <-> 14 PT
CT rail 2 : 19 + 4 = 23 <-> 18 PT
CT rail 2 : 19 + 5 = 24 <-> 22 PT
CT rail 2 : 25 + 6 = 31 <-> 26 PT (too high)
WEAREDISCOVEREDFLEEATONCE
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not super familiar with the algorithm, but it seems like you could save a bunch of time and memory if first you found the length of the string, then found the number of spaces (possibly using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4235519/counting-number-of-occurrences-of-a-char-in-a-string-in-c)), subtracted those two numbers, and then divided by rail (let's call the resulting number numCols). Then you'd just create one 2D char array, with rail rows and numCols columns. Go through with two for loops (columns nested inside of the rows) inserting the characters in order (making sure to avoid spaces).
Once you've done that,  just read them back out, except this time, nest your rows loop inside your columns loop.

Comment: Thank you this worked, but can you explain why you said divide by rail for the resulting numCols? I'm not sure why this is done.

Comment: I was looking at the algorithm [here](http://www.braingle.com/brainteasers/codes/railfence.php).
You know you need rail number of rows in your 2D array, both to encrypt and decrypt.  You know that your ciphertext has the same number of letters as positions in your 2D array.  Once you know the length of the ciphertext (accounting for spaces), all you need to do to find numCols is divide by rail (the number of rows).