# I can't remove the spaces from a string

Tags: c, arrays, string, spaces

I'm currently doing [this challenge](http://www.reddit.com/r/dailyprogrammer/comments/31thwb/20150408_challenge_209_intermediate_packing_a/) on reddit.

Now my problem is on the bottom of the program (unfinished), but I posted the whole thing in case it might have something to do with the top of it.

Now I'm trying to remove spaces from the string the user is supposed to enter, by putting all the non-space characters into another character array. However, every time I print try to print the string with the supposed removed spaces, it only prints the first word. I, however, want it to print all the words into one single combined word.

For example, when I try to convert `Hello World!`, it's supposed to give me `HelloWorld!`, but it's only giving me `Hello`. I've tried different methods with pointers and whatnot and every time I face the same problem. What's going on here?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    char StringtobePacked[100]; //This is the string the user puts in
    char StringtobePackedWOspaces[100]; //This is gonna be the string without spaces

    int i , o , p; //incrementers/counters

    double AmtfChrsnStrng;
    //ask user for sentence input:
    printf("Please type in sentence so I can pack it into the array:\n");
    scanf("%s" , StringtobePacked);

    //check for the amounts of letters in the sentence minus the spaces
    for (i = 0; StringtobePacked[o] > i ; i++ , o++)
    {
        AmtfChrsnStrng++;

        if (StringtobePacked[o] == ' ')
        {
            AmtfChrsnStrng--;
        };
    };
    //now we know the amounts of letters in the sentence minus the spaces

    //find the root and make that into the array size
    double root = sqrt(AmtfChrsnStrng);    //This is to find the square root of the (number) of letters in the string
    int rootup = ceil(root);  //this is to round up the double
    char PackingArray[rootup][rootup];    //have a two dimensional array to pack sentence into

    //make sure to check wether a sign is a space or not so as to not pack these
    for (i = 0 , o = 0; StringtobePacked[i] != 0; i++)
    {
        if (StringtobePacked[i] != ' ')
        {
            StringtobePackedWOspaces[o] = StringtobePacked[i];
            o++;
        }
    }

    StringtobePackedWOspaces[o] = 0;
    puts(StringtobePackedWOspaces);

    //loop through the sentence in order to pack it into the array
    // after end of column has been reached increment row
    //now don't keep incrementing the column but increment it backwards so letters can be packed upwards

    //print array by looping through ,  first columns then rows

    //the starting position of the packing should be randomised
};
```

Comment: 0) `scanf("%s" , StringtobePacked);` --> `scanf("%99[^\n]" , StringtobePacked);` 1) `StringtobePacked[o] > i` --> `StringtobePacked[o]  != '\0'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use fgets() instead of scanf().

```
scanf("%s" , StringtobePacked);
```

Instead of this use this

```
fgets(StringtobePacked,100,stdin);
```

Beacause scanf() with %s specifer will read input till it encounters whitespace or upto field width if it is specified .
This gave the desired output.

Comment: In contrast to `scanf`, the function `fgets` includes the newline character `\n` into `StringtobePacked`. This has to be considered when counting the letters in `StringtobePacked`. For example, don't stop counting at `\0`, but already at `\n`.

Comment: yes @honk you are right to count without newline then we can do this         `buffer[strcspn(Stringtobepacked, "\n")] = 0;`

Answer (score 0):

You should apply the suggestion as posted by @ameyCU in their question. You should also change `StringtobePacked[o] > i` to `StringtobePacked[o] != '\0'` as mentioned by @BLUEPIXY in their comment. In addition to that you use some variables without initializing them. For example, you use `o` and `AmtfChrsnStrng` in the following lines without first setting them to `0` and `0.0` respectively:

```
for (i = 0; StringtobePacked[o] > i ; i++ , o++)
{
    AmtfChrsnStrng++;
    ...
```

To be on the safe side, you should change:

```
int i , o , p; //incrementers/counters
double AmtfChrsnStrng;
```

to:

```
int i=0, o=0, p=0; //incrementers/counters
double AmtfChrsnStrng = 0.0;
```

Your code might work without these initializations in debug mode, but in release mode it is likely to fail.

Maybe there are more issues with your code, but this should at least fix some of them.

Note: In case you want to improve your loop which counts the amount of letters in the sentence minus the spaces, please take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4235519/2675154). [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4235884/2675154) solution adapted to your variables would look like this:

```
for (i=0; StringtobePacked[i]; StringtobePacked[i]!=' ' ? i++ : *s++);
```

After executing this `for` loop, the variable `i` contains the amount of letters in the sentence minus the spaces.

Answer (score -2):

```
char original[SIZE], packed[SIZE];
double amt = 0.0;

scanf("%f", original);

for (char * op = original, * pp = packed; *op; op++)
{
    if (!isspace(*op))
    {
        *pp++ = *op;
        amt++;
    }
}
int dim = (int) ceil(sqrt(amt));
```

When processing strings in C, just walk pointers across the source and destination buffers.  Pointers are the very essence of C, get comfortable with them.  This will leave you with the array dimensions in *dim*.