# How do you count the number of occurences of a letter in a given word?

Tags: c

Hi how would you count the number of occurences in the given word like shown below because with the program I have right now it doesn't seem to room correctly.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
 char a;
 char lang[] = "pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis";
 char i = 0;
 char count = 0;


 printf("pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis\n");
 printf("\nEnter the letter you want to find the number of\n");
 scanf("%c", &lang);
 for (i = 0; i <= 46; i++)
  if (a == lang[i]) {
   count++;
  }
 printf("Number of %c is %d..\n", a, count);

 return 0;
```

Comment: You never appear to set `a`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4235519/counting-number-of-occurrences-of-a-char-in-a-string-in-c

Answer (score 0):

Your scanf is the problem.

Try:

```
 scanf("%c",&a);
```

Comment: Hi but it keeps giving me an error that says "unresolved external symbol"

Comment: "unresolved external symbol" is a link error, when it cannot find the implementation of a function used in program. In your program, we only have print,scanf. So most likely check ur installation and paths of libraries.

Answer (score 0):

declare `count` as `int` instead of `char`
also change scanf to take input `a`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
 char a;
 char lang[] = "pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis";
 char i = 0;
 int count = 0;


 printf("pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis\n");
 printf("\nEnter the letter you want to find the number of\n");
 scanf("%c", &a);
 for (i = 0; i <= 46; i++)
  if (a == lang[i]) {
   count++;
  }
 printf("Number of %c is %d..\n", a, count);

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: "declare count as `int` instead of `char`" is a good idea, but not needed.  Accumulating  the count in a `char`, though more limited that `int`, is OK.

Answer (score 0):

You probably shouldn't hard code the max length of the string (46) if at all possible in case you are given a longer string, but assuming it's an assigned assignment that is set it shouldn't be a problem.

i and count should also be ints if possible for a bigger size count. And &lang should be &a since lang is already assigned while a is your checker.